# iPad: Create a logfile that gets continuously updated?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, file, logging

I want to create a file for my logs. But how can I continue on writing logs into one single file? For the first use I create the file and save my first log in it. But how can I continue on writing on this file without deleting the previous log messages?

Comment: This is not related to Xcode, rather to Cocoa Touch. Retagged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSFileHandle *h = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"MyFile.log"];
[h seekToEndOfFile];

// log
[h writeData:[@"Hello World! 2nd time" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// close when not needed anymore
[h closeFile];
```

Comment: Nice solution, do you also have a way how I can combine this with a logging pattern? I would generally think of creating a Logging class, setting a method using your code to incrementally write in my logging file and then use this method for all my error logs.

Comment: @userXXX that's a reasonable approach.